# Login user's account into Ejabberd Server by API Rest

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie of the Ejabberd. I installed server Ejabberd with admin account and then create some other account user. I tried login user with Ejabberd's API rest but not a way. I research google then found login with smack (library support for java in order to interact Ejabberd command). I wondering whether i can login user account by API Rest of Ejabberd. Thanks all.

Comment: Can you tell which ejabberd version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.You can not login to user with ejabberd rest api because it is not implemented in ejabberd.

Comment: thank your answer. What is a way in order to login but not use admin interface ? Ex library support for client

Comment: You can use any xmpp client to login ejabberd.There are so many open source xmpp client like Gajjim.